# Vowels and Consonants

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, node.js

From HackerRank's 10 Days of JavaScript, [Day2: Loops](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-loops/problem):

> Complete the vowelsAndConsonants function in the editor below. It has one parameter, a string,s, consisting of lowercase English alphabetic letters (i.e., a through z). The function must do the following:
>
> First, print each vowel in s on a new line. The English vowels are a, e, i, o, and u, and each vowel must be printed in the same order as it appeared in s.
>   Second, print each consonant (i.e., non-vowel) in s on a new line in the same order as it appeared in s.

The following code is in JavaScript. The code runs perfectly fine, just finding a way to make it better.

```
function vowelsAndConsonants(s) {
    let sp = s.split("");
    let arr1 =[];
    let arr2 =[];
    for(let i=0;i<sp.length;i++)
    {
        if(sp[i]=='a'||sp[i]=='e'||sp[i]=='i'||sp[i]=='o'||sp[i]=='u'){
            arr1.push(sp[i]);
        }else{
            arr2.push(sp[i]);
        }
    }
    for(let i = 0;i<arr1.length;i++){
        console.log(arr1[i]);
    }
    for(let i = 0;i<arr2.length;i++){
        console.log(arr2[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what your code is actually doing. Your description is very hard to decipher.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have edited the description so that it will be easier to decipher.

Comment: Much better, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a short review;

- `arr1` and `arr2` are terrible names, we could call them `consonants` and `vowels`
- accessing `sp[i]` so often is not efficient, I would store that value in a variable
- when dealing with lists, consider going functional (using `forEach`, `map`, `reduce`, `join` etc.)
- `sp` is not a great name
- There is a nicer way to iterate over the characters of a string with `for( of )`

Finally, I wanted to provide the below as an example where I incorporate the above points;

```
function vowelsAndConsonants2(s) {
  const vowels = [],
    consonants = [];

  for(const c of s){
    if('aeiou'.includes(c)){
      vowels.push(c);
    }else{
      consonants.push(c);
    }
  }
  console.log(vowels.join("\n"));
  console.log(consonants.join("\n"));
}
```

Comment: in the example code `c` becomes a global variable because it isn't declared with a scope keyword - I'd recommend `const`...

Comment: Good point, fixed.